# Redirecting A Specific Tab Firefox Add On

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm writing an exntension for firefox. Basically by using getElementsByClassName, I'm searching for a specific class and if there's any hit, I'm redirecting the page by using: gBrowser.loadURI
The problem is if I open a link by middle mouse button, that link is opened in the background tab. So if there's any hit for the above class criteria in that page, the active tab is redirected instead of the bacground one, which is a wrong behaviour. 
So basically I want to use a similar loadURI function but for a specific tab, not the current active tab. 
Instead of loadURI I can also use window.location = "http://www.google.com/". But somehow when I use window.location, every button in the ff window disappears, as if full view.
Do you have any idea for redirecting the inactive tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using code like this (seems so, please provide your code anyway for future reference):

```
function pageLoad(event) {
  var doc = event.originalTarget;
  if (/* doc matches class */) {
    gBrowser.loadURI(newURI, ...);
  }
}

addEventListener("load", function () {
  gBrowser.addEventListener("load", pageLoad, true);
}, false);
```

Change the listener to something like this:

```
function pageLoad(event) {
  var doc = event.originalTarget;
  if (/* doc matches class */) {
    gBrowser.getBrowserForDocument(doc).loadURI(newURI, ...);
  }
}
```

Of course, it is best served with a grain of error handling.

See [`<tabbrowser>` aka. `gBrowser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/tabbrowser) and [`browser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/browser) (that one `getBrowserForDocument()` returns).

(I did this from memory; you may need to fiddle with it a bit)